# Encryption in small string

Tags: android, encryption

I wish to encrypt small string (GPS coordinnates) then I send to a server on the Internet. I do this on Android.

I have already implemented a solution with public/private key but the result is a long string, I can't send this to the Internet because I have to work with small network quota.

Do you know if a solution exist to encrypt without increasing the size of the data ? It could be a simple algorithm (no need public/private key) but something interesting for the security.

Is there a solution ?

Comment: What is "a long string?" 40 characters? 100? 2000? What encryption method are you using? Some encryption schemes use padding to prevent guessing the (type of) payload, that may be the cause of the larger string. And finally: why not rely on TLS/SSL for sending the data, why do the encryption yourself?

Comment: For symmetric cryptography you can look at Format Preserving Encryption. For asymmetric encryption you might want to look at ECIES. None of these are a direct recommendation as we don't know the security requirements of your system.

Comment: I should I give you more information.

I am writing a firmware for a GPS device (GPS + 4G). The device has a SIM with a small amount of data available.
The device send some information "not important" like date but also send the GPS coordinates are floats "latitude/longitude".
I wish to encrypt the coordonnates but I can't transform 14 digits to 500 digits :)

Exemple of coordinates : 7.66381,48.88094 (can be negative value). 

These data is sensible because this is the localization of the user. Off course it's not highly sensible, the users are "simple" individual (not army ...).

Answer (score -1):

An encryption that preserves the message length will lack security but if that is what you want, consider using Caesar code. This is a substitution cipher in which each letter in the plaintext is replaced by a letter "some secret number" of positions down the alphabet. An attacker can easily search for that secret fixed number. Make the attacker's job harder by devising a rotating sequence of different secret numbers (that only the intended receiver knows). For ultimate security use a "one-time pad" that can be any arbitrary text known to coder and decoder, an obscure Bible verse will do. Encrypt each character of the plaintext by XOR logic combination with the corresponding character of the one-time pad. The decoder just repeats the XOR with the same character of his one-time pad.